# How can I use EMPTY to display an error when fetched array is empty (beginner)

Tags: if-statement, syntax, return-value, fetch, is-empty

I am a beginner, and I think there is a detail which I am not seeing that stops my code from functioning. I have been trying to understand what is going on for hours. I would like that if my $data is empty, an error message be displayed. It doesn't happen. I am at a loss to understand what is wrong with this code.

```
    try {$database = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=miniblog', 'root', '');}
catch(Exception $e) {die('horror : '.$e->getmessage());}
    $answer = $database->query('SELECT id, content FROM blog WHERE id= ' . $_GET['id'] . ' ' ) ;


// Instruct display conditions

        while ($data = $answer->fetch()) 
        { 
        if (empty($data))
        {echo "ERROR there is no such article" ;}
        else
        {echo '<h3 class="news">' . ($data['content']) . '</h3>';}          
        }
```

Comment: The answer was simple. My mistake was to try and use empty inside a while statement. While will not run at all if it isn't true!

I didn't even need to use empty, all I had to do was to use an if statement instead of a while statement:

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be solved using if statement. The while statement failed to produce a error in case it was false, because while statements won't even run if it's false.

Using empty is also unecessary if you use if:

```
 favorite
```

I am a beginner, and I think there is a detail which I am not seeing that stops my code from functioning. I have been trying to understand what is going on for hours. I would like that if my $data is empty, an error message be displayed. It doesn't happen. I am at a loss to understand what is wrong with this code.

```
try {$database = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=miniblog', 'root', '');}
```

catch(Exception $e) {die('horror : '.$e->getmessage());}
    $answer = $database->query('SELECT id, content FROM blog WHERE id= ' . $_GET['id'] . ' ' ) ;
                // Instruct display conditions
            if ($data = $answer->fetch()) 
            {echo ' Article ' . $_GET['id'] . '' . ($data['content']) . '';}
            else
            {echo "ERROR there is no such article" ;}
            // close loop
            $answer->CloseCursor();

Problem Solved :D